# Oracle : Search between two Timestamps is not working

Tags: oracle, timestamp, between

I am trying query the records between two timestamp in oracle.
Timestamp value in db is "02-JUL-14 02.24.04.000000000 PM"

```
select * 
from event_detl 
where START_DT 
 between to_timestamp('02-07-2014 02:24:03', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
  and to_timestamp('02-07-2014 02:24:05', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Currently above query is not returning any record though record exists.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timestamp as `02.24.04 PM` is translated in a HH24 format to   `14.24.04`

For the  timestamp `02-JUL-14 02.24.04.000000000 PM`, the solution is :

```
select * 
from event_detl 
where START_DT 
 between to_timestamp('02-07-2014 14:24:03', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
  and to_timestamp('02-07-2014 14:24:05', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more commentary?  Pointing out that when you use the HH24 format mask, 2:24:04 PM is 14:24:04 not 02:24:04 would be helpful.  Otherwise, it takes a moment to identify how your code differs from the original code.